# code protection php chargeback issue

Tags: php, paypal

today i've approached by a client asking me to do major revamp on website and offering good money.

However, the payment method he offering is via credit card - paypal, only method available to him.

So, my question now is, what should i do to protect myself from paypal chargeback?

Is there **any protection i can add to my php codes to protect** me from this kind of event incase it occured?

Thank you

Comment: Ask him to get a moneybookers account. While your client may be trustworthy (never inject any harmcode), Paypal isn't.

Comment: @mario: What makes Moneybookers and more trustworthy than PayPal?

Comment: @animuson: MB never charges back or freezes your account. Unlike Paypal it's a real bank in the UK. And there's customer service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you're thinking of putting something into the code is absurd. Putting something in the code will do nothing in the end. If you're smart, you will get all of his contact information and **verify it** before working with him and log any and all conversations. Then if he attempts a chargeback, you can take legal action against him to retrieve the funds.

> The seller and PayPal can work together to dispute the chargeback with the buyer's credit card company. While the chargeback is being disputed, PayPal will debit the seller’s account for the amount in question. If PayPal and the seller ultimately win the chargeback dispute, the credit card company will reimburse PayPal for the chargeback, and PayPal will transfer the recovered funds back to the seller. Depending on the credit card company involved, the process may take up to 75 days.

From: [Paypal - Chargeback FAQ](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/securitycenter/sell/ChargebackFAQ-outside)

Comment: Too, putting hooks into the code makes _you_ look like the deceptive one. Be professional, invoice him properly and make sure you have a valid business license in the area you work.